# JBoss working project with EJB can't get deployed on Tomcat Plume

Tags: maven, jpa, jakarta-ee, jboss, tomee-7

Structure of project: pom-root, ear project that's dependent on ejb and war. War project also depends on ejb. Everything is created by `mvn archetype:generate` and managed in IDEA. The overall project gets cleaned and packaged and then the ear is being deployed on TomcatEE Plume 7.0.5.

Task: get user data from servlet and to persist it with JPA + hibernate to PostgreSQL.

Entity class: NewUser

Stateless class: UserEJB

Maven clean and install goes well, but when I start it with Tomcat the following error prevents ear to be deployed:

```
    26-Aug-2018 18:24:37.684 INFO [http-nio-8002-exec-5] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate PersistenceUnit(name=userUnit, provider=org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider) - provider time 282ms
    26-Aug-2018 18:24:37.684 INFO [http-nio-8002-exec-5] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: ...\jpaTomcat\ear\target\ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT
    26-Aug-2018 18:24:38.173 SEVERE [http-nio-8002-exec-5] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication undeployException original cause
     java.lang.Exception: deployment not found: RegisterEJB
```

NewUser class:

```
package com.jeorgius.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "newuser", schema = "userdata")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "h", sequenceName = "userdata.hibernate_sequence")
public class NewUser implements Serializable {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "h")
    private Integer id;
    private String nick;
    private String email;
    private String pw;

    public String getNick() {
        return nick;
    }

    public void setNick(String nick) {
        this.nick = nick;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPw() {
        return pw;
    }

    public void setPw(String pw) {
        this.pw = pw;
    }
}
```

RegisterEJB class:

```
package com.jeorgius.ejb;

import com.jeorgius.entities.NewUser;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class RegisterEJB {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "userUnit")
    EntityManager em;

    public void createUser(String nick, String email, String pw) {
        NewUser newUser = new NewUser();
        newUser.setNick(nick);
        newUser.setEmail(email);
        newUser.setPw(pw);

        em.persist(newUser);
    }
}
```

index.jsp page contains only form to enter nick, email, pw with action to servlet Register:

```
package com.jeorgius.servlets;

import com.jeorgius.ejb.RegisterEJB;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/register")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    RegisterEJB registerEJB = new RegisterEJB();

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String nick = req.getParameter("nick");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String pw = req.getParameter("pw");

        registerEJB.createUser(nick, email, pw);

    }
}
```

persistence.xml on ejb-project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="userUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.jeorgius.entities.NewUser</class>
        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jeorgius" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234" />

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

ejb-project pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>jpaTomcat</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.jeorgius</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <artifactId>back</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>back</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>jpaTomcat</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

war-project pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>jpaTomcat</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.jeorgius</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <artifactId>front</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>front</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jeorgius</groupId>
            <artifactId>back</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

ear-project pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>jpaTomcat</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.jeorgius</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <artifactId>ear</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>ear</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jeorgius</groupId>
            <artifactId>back</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jeorgius</groupId>
            <artifactId>front</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The exact same project runs well on JBoss server, except for the fact that I use a .xml datasource on JBoss, so persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="userUnit">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/jeorgiusDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.jeorgius.entities.Signup</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I just wanted to test my app on TomcatEE, on which I failed before using JBoss, but I still can't figure out what's wrong. TomcatEE and Tomcat Plume are supposed to work with EJB and JPA.

Tomcat Plume was also used in one of the examples on youtube and it worked well, but the guy who made the video added project libraries manually without Maven. I didn't try to do it myself yet though, but that would leave issue with building it with maven.

I spent a lot of time trying out different stuff. Feel free to ask me questions, if anything is unclear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think TomEE does not like that `<packaging>ejb</packaging>`. If you move `RegisterEJB` to the same project/module where your servlet is then I believe it will work (no ear, just one war file).

If you want to have `RegisterEJB` in a different artifact I would use `<packaging>jar</packaging>`.

Also this looks strange:

```
@EJB
RegisterEJB registerEJB = new RegisterEJB();
```

It should be:

```
@EJB
RegisterEJB registerEJB;
```

`@Inject` will also work and with that you can change your EJB to something else and it will still work.

Comment: Thanks! I'm out on PTO, so when I return, I will try. New instance of EJB was created in a desperate attempt to make it work, so I will also remove it. Simple @Inject didn't work, so my bet is on .jar as a package for the file that contains EJB